# JOIN on two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables:

`user`:

```
id   username       name
1aa   sample.user    Sample User
```

and `credential`:

```
id  userId  type         value
1   1aa     salt         abc123
2   1aa     password     samplehashpassword
```

I want to perform a query to get the following result (one row for every user):

```
userId  username      name            type      value     type        value
1aa     sample.user   Sample User     salt      abc123    password    samplehashpassword
```

Right now I am executing this query:

```
SELECT
    "userId", username, name, type, value
FROM
    public.user u 
INNER JOIN public.credential c
    ON u.id = c."userId";
```

This results in:

```
userId  username      name            type      value
1aa     sample.user   Sample User     salt      abc123

userId  username      name            type      value
1aa     sample.user   Sample User     password  samplehashpassword
```

I want a single row for a user. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `join`s:

```
SELECT u.*, cs.type, cs.value, cp.type, cp.value
FROM public.user u INNER JOIN
     public.credential cs
     ON u.id = cs."userId" AND cs.type = 'salt' INNER JOIN
     public.credential cp
     ON u.id = cp."userId" AND cp.type = 'password';
```

Comment: perfect, this is what I need